# Get images by a slug in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to Wordpress and I am trying to make a function that loads images under a media category. The media category has a slug that I want to pass into the function. If there is an easier way to do this please let me know. Below is my code so far:

**Functions.php**

```
function get_image_by_slug($slug) {
   $query_images_args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'post_mime_type' =>'image',
   'post_status' => 'inherit',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'attachment_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $slug,
    ),
  ),
);
$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
   $images[]= $image->guid;
}

return $images;
}

function display_image_by_slug() {
   $imgs = get_image_by_slug($slug);
   $html = '<ul class="list-inline">';

   foreach($imgs as $img) {

       $html .= '<li><img src="' . $img . '" alt="" /></li>';

   }

   $html .= '</ul>';

   return $html;
}

add_filter('display_slugs','display_image_by_slug');
```

In page

```
<?php apply_filter('display slugs', 'test_slug');?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking around the Wordpress docs and understanding Naresh's answer I was able to come up with my own answer. Here it is...

```
$id = 'YOUR SLUG';

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media_category', // your taxonomy
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $id // term id (id of the media category)
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>'. wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() );
        if(empty_content(get_the_content())){
            echo '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<p><a href="'.get_the_content().'">'.get_the_excerpt().'</a></p></li>';
        }
    }
} else {
    // no attachments found
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2):

An attachment of image or file is just a post with the `post_status = inherit` and the `post_type = attachment` and it is saved into the `wp_post` & `wp_postmeta` , so can be queried with `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

**Note:** The slug (post_name) is **unique** per `post type`.

> You have to pass your slug in the query by replacing `YOUR-SLUG` in this place. `&name=YOUR-SLUG`

```
$_head = get_posts('post_type=attachment&name=YOUR-SLUG&posts_per_page=1&post_status=inherit');
$header = $_head ? array_pop($_head) : null;  
$header_url = $header ? wp_get_attachment_url($header->ID) : '';
```

Another Method you can build your own custom function with the help that i have provided below.

```
function get_attachment_url_by_slug( $slug ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'name' => sanitize_title($slug),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
);
$_head = get_posts( $args );
$header = $_head ? array_pop($_head) : null;
return $header ? wp_get_attachment_url($header->ID) : '';
```

and then you can call using this function.

```
$header_url = get_attachment_url_by_slug('YOUR-SLUG');
```

Comment: However, I am not just retrieving a single image, but instead I want to retrieve all the images that have that slug. I have 3 images under a media category slug of 'test'.

Comment: Change the `posts_per_page=-1`, and it will fetch you all the data that are available in the media category slug that you have.

Comment: @Elli. If so after applying this you face error share thought over here and we shall discuss about your strategy to get the image.

Comment: Do I run this in a loop?

Comment: This is returning images that do not have the passed in slug/media category